# Problema AJAX(No se envía) Laravel5.1

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Tengo que enviar un formulario por medio de Ajax en laravel, y tengo 2 problemas:

El primero es que no se envía por Ajax.

El segundo es que si se enviase, tendría que salir un error de que falta el `csrf_field`.

Digo el segundo punto, porque cuando inspecciono la página el input `type=hidden` tiene `value=""`

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" value="<?php  csrf_field();;?>" id="token">
       <input type="text"  name="txtcorreo" id="idtxtcorreo" value="">
       <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Identificarse"  id="Registro" > 
   </form>
```

Darse cuenta que le he quitado el action para que lo coja por Ajax

También he quitado el `value="?php ECHO  "` porque al poner `echo` ***se pintaba en el html*** "id="token"> y por eso al quitar echo cuando inspecciono el input hidden no tiene value... pero si lo pongo pinta el "id="token">

```
 $("#Registro").click(function () {
            var dato = $("#idtxtcorreo").val();
            var route = "http://localhost/MacAltia/public/Login";
            var token =$("#token").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: route, 
                headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN'}
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {genre: dato}
            })
        });
```

Routes

```
Route::post('Login', "ControladorSistema@Login");
```

Controlador

```
 public function Login(Request $request) {

         if($request->ajax()){
             echo "hay ajax";
         }else{
             echo "no hay";
         }
    }
```

Finalmente cuando le doy a botón enviar, detecta que el formulario no tiene action, pero debería cogerlo por ajax...

```
1/1
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 750
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 659
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despues de lo hablado por el chat, la vista deberia quedar así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Mio -->
    <title>Página de Inicio</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="../Css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/fontello.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../Imgs/icono.ico" />

    <!-- AÑADIDO ESTE META -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<!-- Mio -->

<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- FIN Bootstrap 4 -->



</head>
<body>

<!-- CABECERA -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl bg-light row">
<img src="../Imgs/logo.png" alt="logo.png">
<div class="offset-md-8 offset-sm-8"></div>
<!-- Links -->
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">Acceder</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="Form_Crear_Cuenta">Crear Cuenta</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<!-- FIN CABECERA -->

<main>
<!-- FORMULARIO -->
<div class="container">
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <form method="POST" id="formulario">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="Correo" >Correo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtcorreo" id="idtxtcorreo" placeholder="Escribe el correo" value="" required>
            <label for="Contrasenna" >Contraseña: </label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtpass" id="idtxtpass" placeholder="Escribe la contraseña" value="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group offset-md-8 " >
            <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Identificarse" class="btn btn-primary" id="Registro" >
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#demo2" data-toggle="collapse">Recuperar Contraseña</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
    <!-- FIN FORMULARIO -->

<div id="demo2" class="collapse container">
    <form action='RecuperarPass' id="idform_cambiar" method='POST'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for='RecuperarPass'>Introduce un correo</label>
            <input type='text' name='email_recuperarpass' placeholder="Introduce el correo" class="form-control" value='' required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group offset-md-9 " >
            <input type="submit" name="btnrecuperarPass" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" >
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#demo2" data-toggle="collapse">Deshacer</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</main>
<script>

$("#formulario").on('submit', function(evt){ 
    evt.preventDefault();  // Esto anula el comportamiento por defecto del formulario
    var dato = $("#idtxtcorreo").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Login",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        //dataType: 'json',
        data: {genre: dato}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Respuesta servidor: " + msg );
    });
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo primero que debes hacer es usar **blade** ¿para que imprimer con `<php? echo...`? en su lugar usa:

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

Luego deberás detener la acción por defecto del formulario (quitarle valor al atributo `action` no elimina el envío por método convencional) para esto tenemos que agregar un evento `submit` al formulario y no un evento `click` al botón:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="formulario">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php  csrf_field();;?>" id="token">
    <input type="text"  name="txtcorreo" id="idtxtcorreo" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Identificarse"  id="Registro" > 
</form> 

$("#formulario").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Esto anula el comportamiento por defecto del formulario

    var dato = $("#idtxtcorreo").val();
    var route = "http://localhost/MacAltia/public/Login";
    var token =$("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: route, 
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN'}
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {genre: dato}
    });
});
```

Creo que en el `route` no es necesario copiar la url completa, no estoy seguro pero podrías dejarlo así:

```
var route = "/Login";
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_field() }}" id="token">`

Laravel transforma el código Blade en código PHP, y ese {{ csrf_field() }} es un <?php echo csrf_field();; ?>

Puedes encontrarlo en storage->frameworks->views->cualquier vista que incluya ese código csrf.

Por lo tanto si pongo <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_field() }}" id="token">

`El Html pinta "id="token"> Completamente visible. Por eso mismo cogí su código PHP a "Pelo" quitándo el echo `

Comment: @EduBw yo se que blade convierte sus vistas a php pero lo mejor es usar blade hasta donde más se permita, solo para tener buenas prácticas, ahora me parece super extraño que al imprimir el token te muestre el input o eso es lo que entiendo

Comment: Imprime en el html el " que es el final del value e id="token">

Comment: Además con el e.preventDefault();se sigue enviando el formulario

Comment: @EduBw acabo de mirar ladocumentación de Laravel y vi esto, inténtalo así: <form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>... es extraño que no funcione el preventDefault() lo has hecho tal cual?

Comment: No para el envío del formulario. Ya no pinta el html el id="token" pero al darle al botón enviar sale en la url : "localhost/profile"

Comment: @EduBw ahhh no estas usando un virtualhost? si no lo estás usando entonces si debes pasar tu ruta completa...pense que lo usabas laravel se trabaja de buena manera con ello

Comment: Uso Laravel en localhost. De todos modos debería coger la ruta por el ajax , no ? porque pongo la URL: en el ajax. Sigue sin parar el evento... y ahora le he puesto  $("#Registro").submit(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault(); Que es el id del btn submit

Comment: @EduBw nono, mira bien mi ejemplo, el evento submit se debe asignar al formulario no al botón

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70191/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-edubw).